# How to print array in cyclic permutation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty to print array with all its values cyclically permuted by p elements
to the left. Like my input array is [1,2,3,4] and output should be [3,4,1,2] but I am only getting 1 in my console.Can Anyone Help me please?

```
var arr= [1, 2, 3, 4];
  console.log(pRow(arr,2));

//myQ() this is the constructor of the queue data structure that I have created and I need to use this to print array in cyclically permuted way.

function Queue() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.head = function () {
        return this.arr[0];
    };
    this.dequeue = function () {
        if (this.arr.length == 0) {
            return "Queue underflow!";
        } else {
            return this.arr.shift();
        }
    };
    this.enqueue = function (o) {
        this.arr.push(o);
    };
    this.isEmpty = function () {
        return this.arr.length == 0;
    };

}

function pRow(arr, p) {

    var myQueue = new Queue();
    myQueue.arr = arr;
    myQueue.enqueue(p);
    return myQueue.dequeue();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you return a single element with [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

Instead, you could take[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a given offset.

```js
function pRow(array, offset) {
    return [
        ...array.slice(offset % array.length),
        ...array.slice(0, offset % array.length)
    ];
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(pRow(arr, 2));
```

With classes. `pRow` returns a new shifted queue instance.

```js
class Queue {
    constructor(array = []) {
        this.array = [...array];
    }

    dequeue() {
        return this.array.length === 0
            ? "Queue underflow!"
            : this.array.shift();
    }

    enqueue(o) {
        this.array.push(o);
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.array.length === 0;
    }

    shift(p) {
        const
            pQueue = new Queue,
            temp = [];

        p %= arr.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < p && !this.isEmpty(); i++) temp.push(this.dequeue());

        while (!this.isEmpty()) pQueue.enqueue(this.dequeue());

        while (temp.length) pQueue.enqueue(temp.shift());

        return pQueue;
    }
}

function pRow(arr, p) {
    return new Queue(arr).shift(p);
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(pRow(arr, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I want to use myQ() in pRow() function to return array because I want to know how it work with object.

Comment: you structure does not refelect a linked list with a pointer to the actual element. you may ned to get this structure first and then wind it to the wanted position and if you reached an end, you need to start at the head item. i am not sure, if you better use a correctly shifted array at first or do this later. it is up to you to desiugn the wanted behaviour. the question is in this point open.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Can u please show me with code by editing ur answer because I am preparing for interview and  here I am little bit confused.

Comment: i am confused as well. what should be the internal structure of the queue? what should be the result of `pRow`? why is it not a function of the class?

Comment: By using myQ() object The function pRow() should reproduce the process  of enqueuing the values in the array into an empty queue, permute the queue, then push the values in the queue to an empty array. This final array is the one that
will be returned.

Comment: but you have no queue in your code. usually a queue has three functions, add to end, pop from start and get the length. i see nothing of it in your code. for a cyclic shift, you need a new queue which get filled from the old one by getting the first part until the wanted offset, store it, get the rest as new queue and add the first part to the end of the queue. then process the new queue.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can u please check.Many Thanks.